# How to prove the right identity in setoid in Agda

Tags: algebra, agda, integer-arithmetic

I wanted to prove group properties over integer. I found the setoid representation of integer makes proof easy.

`ℤ` is defined as `(ℕ , ℕ)` such that `(a , b)` represents `a - b`

```
zero : ℤ
zero = 0 , 0
```

I have already proven

```
leftIdZ : (a : ℤ) → zero + a ≡ a
rightIdZ : (a : ℤ) → a + zero ≡ a
```

`zpre` and `zsuc` is defined as

```
zsuc : ℤ → ℤ
zsuc (m , n) = suc m , n

zpre : ℤ → ℤ
zpre (m , n) = m , suc n
```

I would like to prove the commutativity of addition:

```
commZ-+ : (a b : ℤ) → a + b ≡ b + a
commZ-+ (ℕ.zero , ℕ.zero) b = sym (trans (rightIdZ b) (sym (leftIdZ b)))
commZ-+ (ℕ.zero , suc x₁) (ℕ.zero , ℕ.zero) = rightIdZ (ℕ.zero , suc x₁)
commZ-+ (ℕ.zero , suc x₁) (ℕ.zero , suc x₃) = cong zpre {!!}
commZ-+ (ℕ.zero , suc x₁) (suc x₂ , x₃) = cong zsuc {!!}
commZ-+ (suc x , x₁) (x₂ , x₃) = {!!}
```

I found somewhere they are proving this by using agda library. But i tried in that way (above).

The problem reduced to proof `0 , (x₁ ℕ.+ suc x₃) ≡ 0 , (x₃ ℕ.+ suc x₁)`

I had proof of this lemma : `lemma-+succ : ∀ a b → suc a + b ≡ a + suc b`
I know some how this lemma will be used to prove above reduced goal but it return type is `Set` whereas above that is expecting integer.

Is there any efficient way of doing this?? or How should i do this?? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem description can be simplified to defining `problem` in the following code:

```
open import Data.Product
open import Data.Nat as ℕ
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

postulate lemma-+succ : ∀ a b → suc a ℕ.+ b ≡ a ℕ.+ suc b

problem : ∀ x₁ x₃ → 0 ,′ (x₁ ℕ.+ suc x₃) ≡ 0 ,′ (x₃ ℕ.+ suc x₁)
problem = ?
```

First of all, let's get rid of that `0,` part: if `x ≡ y`, then `0, x ≡ 0, y` by simple congruence:

```
problem : ∀ x₁ x₃ → 0 ,′ (x₁ ℕ.+ suc x₃) ≡ 0 ,′ (x₃ ℕ.+ suc x₁)
problem x₁ x₃ = cong (λ y → 0 , y) ?
```

So that leaves us with just the commutativity of natural addition: the type of the hole is `x₁ + suc x₃ ≡ x₃ + suc x₁`.

This should give you enough hints to finish what you are trying to do: `lemma-+succ` is not directly applicable; can you prove `lemma-+comm : ∀ a b → a ℕ.+ b ≡ b ℕ.+ a`?

Comment: Now I get that if any of side is equal I can reduced it by using lambda expression. But what if we can not reduce it for example. `x₂ , (x₁ ℕ.+ 0) ≡ (x₂ ℕ.+ 0) , x₁.` Here I have proof of each part seperately but i am not able to use cong here.

Comment: So you've looked at [`cong`](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality.html#1036) but didn't find [`cong₂`](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality.html#1274) right next to it?

Comment: Also, even if `cong₂` didn't exist, you could use `trans`itivity to go from `x₂ , (x₁ ℕ.+ 0)` to `x₂ , x₁` to `(x₂ ℕ.+ 0) , x₁`.